# PySpark insertInto overwrite

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to insert data from a data frame into a Hive table. I have been able to do so successfully using
`df.write.insertInto("db1.table1", overwrite = True)`.

I am just a little confused about the `overwrite = True` part -- I tried running it multiple times and it seemed to append, not overwrite. There wasn't too much in the docs, but when should I set overwrite to `False` vs. `True`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`df.insertInto`** works only if **`table already exis`ts** in hive.

**`df.write.insertInto("db.table1",overwrite=False)`** will **`append`** the data to the existing hive table.

**`df.write.insertInto("db.table1",overwrite=True)`** will **`overwrite`** the data in hive table.

**Example:**

```
df.show()
#+----+---+                                                                                                                                                                              
#|name| id|
#+----+---+
#|   a|  1|
#|   b|  2|
#+----+---+

#save the table to hive
df.write.saveAsTable("default.table1")

#from hive
#hive> select * from table1;
#OK
#a       1
#b       2

df.write.insertInto("moch.table1",overwrite=True)

#from hive
#hive> select * from table1;
#OK
#a       1
#b       2

#appending data to hive
df.write.insertInto("moch.table1",overwrite=False)

#from hive
#hive> select * from table1;
#OK
#a       1
#b       2
#a       1
#b       2
```

Comment: How to insertInto a S3 location for which a hive table is not created? The ETL job is only to load the data to S3 to be consumable by downstream processes but a table is not required to create

Comment: Thanks for the helpful user. A minor suggestion to improve the example is to use a different dataframe for demonstrating `df.write.insertInto("moch.table1",overwrite=True)`. Right now, it is not clear if the table itself gets overwritten or the duplicate rows get updated.

Comment: What happens when the output table is partitioned? Does it overwrite the whole table or just the partition?